# Windows 8 not booting from Grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

Okay so here is the thing. First I want to let you know that I know absolutely nothing about Linux.

So I installed Ubuntu along with my windows 8. When restarted the computer, windows 8 was booted without anyone asking me what OS I wanted, so googling it made me download EasyBCD, which mess with the Bios or something. So downloaded it, added an entry for Ubuntu, restarted, and Windows Boot asked me what OS I want, and everything worked fine, until I messed things up. I booted Windows 8, went to EasyBCD, made Ubuntu the default OS, and checked "Skip the Boot Menu". Now every time I start my PC, Ubuntu is started. Pretty good. Now the thing is, how can I start my windows 8 if I ever want to? Googling for like an hour made me install Grub Customizer, messed a little with it, and now when I start my PC, a Grub shows up with a list of the OS I have, repair mode for Ubuntu, and memory test. Now if I select Windows 8, the screen turns black with two white sentences at the top for less than half a second, then another black screen with around 3,4 sentences which goes to fast I can't read, and then it go back to GRUB list as if nothing happened. Ubuntu boots fine, I just can't start Windows 8. Oh yeah I also disabled Secure Boot, since googling told me that would work, but it didn't. So yeah, if anyone can help me, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please hold off on the profanity.  We understand the frustration, but it'd be a better environment if we could keep it more intellectual and civil.  The assistance will be better.

Comment: You have to turn off Windows fast start up or its always on hibernation first. Grub will not boot into a hibernated system. But if UEFI you should be able to go directly to UEFI boot menu often f10 or f12 and boot Windows. You also need to remove EasyBCD as with UEFI it just makes things more difficult, some with BIOS that are primarily WIndows users may use it, but not recommended as it used very old grub4dos and requires grub2 to be installed in a mode that is not recommended.

Comment: @oldfred How do I turn off Window?

Comment: That is really a Windows question: Fast Startup off (always on hibernation)
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324331&p=13488472#post13488472 and:
http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html or:
http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.htmlold
More explanation of NTFS driver & Windows hibernation
http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation